# What is the terminology for the length of time an individual data point represents?

Tags: time-series, terminology, mathematical-statistics

I'm having trouble conceptualizing this or putting it into word(s). It has been bothering me off and on for months now.

As an example (financial, as that's all I know), let's say that Sarah wants to measure her financial success using two main metrics on a quarterly basis: Gross Income and Net Worth

For both of these metrics, the **periodicity** would be "Quarterly". A key difference between the metrics however, is that Quarterly Gross Income measures the sum of Sarah's income over the span of a Financial Quarter, whereas "Net Worth" is what I would call a "Point in Time" observation that just so happens to be observed on a quarterly basis.

What is the terminology or concept around this "duration of measurement" that I'm missing? Or am I just way off in my way of thinking around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call this "resolution" or more specifically "time resolution": you are sampling a continuous function at discrete time points. You could also refer to a "sampling interval" or "sampling frequency". Your data don't really represent a time interval, they are just sampled at particular points in time; the numbers would change if you shifted the samples by 1 month, but the time resolution would stay constant.

If you were to generate a plot of these data, the resulting trace would represent a discrete approximation of Sarah's net worth at a quarterly resolution.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. If I'm understanding correctly, you would say that Gross Income is sampled quarterly with a quarterly resolution? What would you call the time resolution for "Net Worth"? Or is it just a different type of data that should be treated differently?

Comment: @PatrickAllen I would say "Net worth is sampled quarterly." or "Net worth is plotted at quarterly time resolution." Not both.  Gross Income in this case isn't really *sampled* quarterly, it's been integrated over time. I think people would understand what you meant if you described it the same way as net worth, but other wording might be more appropriate; I might simply say "Gross income per quarter" or "by quarter".

Comment: Ahh, I see what you are saying. Are there discrete classifications for these two different types of data in the field? I.e. Integrated vs Sampled? Obviously it can be important to distinguish between the two during analysis.

Comment: @PatrickAllen In some cases it might matter; I think for the two particular variables you've chosen there isn't any way you'd really treat them differently, because the time course on which each changes tends to be much longer than your sampling frequency.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, there is no specific term for the periodicity for Net Worth. The net worth is like a continuous function and could not be attributed to any specific period. Even if we calculate if in quarter, that information will be applicable for that specific time on that day in that quarter.

For example, let's say Sarah's date of birth is February 10, 1990.  We could say that she was 19 years old in January, 2020. However, we could say that neither she was 19 years old in the quarter Jan-Mar, 2020 nor she was 20 years old in the quarter Jan-Mar, 2020. We couldn't say that she was 19 years on January 1, 2020.

Whenever, we mention the net worth for a specific quarter as per your example, we could say "net worth at the end of the quarter" or "net worth at the beginning of the quarter".

I think I have to search through the literature to give you a more convincing answer than this. I'll keep you posted, unless someone else comes up with the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response! After asking my initial question I found this: https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=3751. It essentially mirrors what both you and I said, with the added mention of the word "integrated". I suppose we could say "Gross Income" is integrated whereas "Net Worth" is not? It doesn't describe the whole "duration" thing I'm looking for, but maybe I'm just off in my thought process.

Comment: Thank for the update. The closest term that I could guess is "instance".

Answer (score 1):

In Economics, there is an standard distinction between so called "flow variables" and "stock variables". Flow variables are those which do not have meaning for a point in time, but rather can be thought of as integrals. Income or production of a certain good are examples. Stock variables have meaning at a point in time: interest rates, prices, etc.